# Vue - Setting the width of a component dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I can't figure out how to dynamically set the width of a component.

I am using the component 'vue-burger-menu' -> https://github.com/mbj36/vue-burger-menu.

To set the width one needs to set the prop `width` to a number. As per the example below:

```
<Slide
      ref="slideToggle"
      disable-esc
      class="slideToggle"
      width="470"
      right
      :burger-icon="false"
      :cross-icon="false"
      disable-outside-click
    >
```

It then sets a helper class - `bm-menu` width to the `width`. I have spent quite a while trying to figure out how to either set the prop's attribute dynamically or dynamically update the style.

For example I tried setting: `this.$refs.slideToggle.$attrs.width = 1000` to no avail.

I can't bind a style to the `bm-menu` class as it's not visible.

How do I set the width so on the click of a button it changes (as per the button example below)?

Thanks for your help!

```
setDrawWidth() {
        this.lineDrawWidth = "200px";
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need binding which uses `:` before props:

```
<Slide
      ref="slideToggle"
      disable-esc
      class="slideToggle"
      :width="width"
      right
      :burger-icon="false"
      :cross-icon="false"
      disable-outside-click
>
```

And then in your `data` in `js` part:

```js
export default {
     data:() => ({   width: '470'  }),
}
```

Now you just need to change `width` variable. For example:

```
export default {
     data:() => ({   width: '470'  }),
     methods:{
          changeWidth(){
               this.width = '1000';
          }
     }
}
```

You can read more about binding variables from the doc: [Vue Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing I had to change in this example if anyone comes looking... the with numbers need to be in quotation marks. i.e "470"

Comment: @tbowden I changed it based on your feedback. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Listen on window width event:

```
data: () => ({
  width: 470
})
created() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.changeWidth);
},
destroyed() {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", this.changeWidth);
},
methods: {
  changeWidth(e) {
    const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.width = screenWidth
  }
}
```

and set width in `Slide` component:

```
<Slide
      ref="slideToggle"
      disable-esc
      class="slideToggle"
      :width="width"
      right
      :burger-icon="false"
      :cross-icon="false"
      disable-outside-click
    >
```